# Por que esse while loop não funciona? (infinito)

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tendo problemas com um while loop no meu código. Por alguma razão, está dando loop infinito. O código é esse:

```
function transf(){

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var compartimento = document.getElementById('compartimento');  

while (compartimento.childNodes.length > 0) {
container.appendChild(compartimento.childNodes[0]);
}  

var alturadocontainer = container.clientHeight;  
var containerlc = container.lastChild;    
var container2 = document.getElementById("container2");

while (alturadocontainer > 100){ 
container2.insertBefore(containerlc, container2.childNodes[0]);    
}

}
```

O primeiro while loop funciona sem problemas. O problema está no segundo. O resultado esperado é que, enquanto a altura do container fosse maior que 100, os últimos elementos do container passassem para o container2 (o que, em tese deveria diminuir a altura do container, mas ao que parece isso não está acontecendo, causando assim o loop infinito). Por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja o ajuste, atualizando o valor das variáveis após a transferência:
*Não cheguei a testar o código.*

```
function transf(){

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var compartimento = document.getElementById('compartimento');  

while (compartimento.childNodes.length > 0) {
container.appendChild(compartimento.childNodes[0]);
}  

var alturadocontainer = container.clientHeight;  
var containerlc = container.lastChild;    
var container2 = document.getElementById("container2");

while (alturadocontainer > 100){ 
container2.insertBefore(containerlc, container2.childNodes[0]);    
var alturadocontainer = container.clientHeight;  
var containerlc = container.lastChild; 
}

}
```

Comment: Valeu, Andrey! Deu certo! Fico muito agradecido.